# is there a reason why I run the command to create superuser but it throws an error that 'email is not a valid UUID field'?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-migrations

I am not new to Django, but I am gaining experience, by working on this project. I use Django 4.2. I created a model for users and ran migrations. I tried to create a superuser, but got an error that 'email is not a valid UUID field'. I understand that 'email' is being passed to the 'UUID' field but I specified that for ID field, so there is a problem with the operation but I can't seem to understand where.

This is my `models.py` file

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.core.exceptions import FieldError


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email must be given!')
        kwargs.setdefault('is_active', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(email, username, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user 
    
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email must be given!')
        kwargs.setdefault('is_active', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        superuser = self.model(email, **kwargs)
        superuser.set_password(password)
        superuser.save(using=self._db)
        return superuser



class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True, null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True, null=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['id', 'email', 'username']
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return super().__str__(self.email)
    
    def has_perms(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_superuser
    
    def get_full_name(self) -> str:
        return self.username
    
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

The commands I ran were:

`py manage.py makemigrations`, `py manage.py migrate`, `py manage.py createsuperuser`

Then I get this error:
`CommandError: “example135@gmail.com” is not a valid UUID.`

I have looked at my models but I don't see any issue yet.
I have tried to recreate the models but still I have the same issue.

Can anyone be of help?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

- Delete **`migrations`** folder of your `user_app`
- Delete **`db.sqlite3`** database file
- run command `python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name`
- run command `python manage.py migrate`
- run command `python manage.py createsuperuser`

NOTE - I think it raises an error because you added some data in the user model, then after you added the `Id` field which automatically generates `UUID`

Comment: it's still saying the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by changing my email field to EmailField(), I also added the db_index attr to the field.